# How to regexp_extract all characters before a hyphen, but if no hyphen exists, all characters before a space - pyspark

Tags: regex, pyspark, data-cleaning

I have some data on bls locations that I'm trying to clean up before aggregating/ grouping by. There is a lot of variation in the names, so I want to use regexp_extract to find like names. Examples of several of the strings

```
hx = hx.DataFrame({
     'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],
     'bls': ['New York-White Plains-Wayne NY-NJ Metropolitan Division',
             'New York-Jersey City-White Plans, NY-NJ Metropolitan Division',
             'New York-White Plains-Wayne, NY-NJ Metropolitan Div',
             'Fayetteville NC',
             'Fayetteville, NC',
             'San Antonio, TX',
             'San Antonio TX',
             'San Antonio-New Braunfels TX',
             'San Antonio-New Braunfels, TX']
```

My idea was to pull out the first area listed before a hyphen (since I want 'New York' not just 'New'). The issue is, in Fayetteville and San Antonio, there is no hyphen. The below works fine for some results but not all. I also am not sure how to pull out just a state.

```
hx = hx.withColumn('bls_first_word', F.regexp_extract(hx.bls, '^\w+', 0))
hx = hx.withColumn('bls_first_section', F.regexp_extract(hx.bls, '^[^^ -]' -]*[^ -], 0))
```

**This is my first time posting to stackoverflow instead of just sifting through previous questions, so my apologies if my formatting is less than desireable.